# Is there a way to autofill YES for every date on a range after a given event occurs once?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to create a table with three columns:

1. A continuous date range
2. Dates where a specific event occurred (likely not occurring every day)
3. Yes for if that event occurred

On the third column, I would like it to populate a YES for every range after the first YES, even if the event does not occur after that time. The purpose of this is to classify an account when they do experience the event. Is this possible on a continuous-time range?

My larger goal is to use this data across multiple accounts to get an idea of the number of accounts that have seen this event over time. Any help would be much appreciated!

The event pages.name is pulled in on a user basis so I will need to join pages.name to users and then users to their given account, allowing me to then view this data for a distinct account. As long as one user in an account hits pages.name, then it should apply for the entire account.

Once pages.name hits, I need to generate a third column with either YES or NO, depending on if that account has had pages.name occur.

Here is a visual of the table I am trying to create. I am using MySQL.
[image: example image]

Comment: which database do you use?

Comment: I am using SQL on Redash

Comment: Hi @RyanK that is a language(sql) not a database. Databases are: Oracle, MySQL, Postgresql...

Comment: Redash is not a database

Comment: Hi Ryan
What you are trying to do is hard to follow with the information you have given. Please provide 1. your table and column structure. 2. Rephrase what you are trying do do. 3. Mention the DB vendor you are using. Usually, you should be able to use a trigger or an event to populate data based on a condition.

Comment: the database is MySQL

Comment: Hi @SyedAfzal. Thanks for your help on this one. I am new to SQL and very new to this forum. I edited my orignal post with some more clarification. let me know if you need more information!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Sorry to say your question still isn't clear. May I suggest you edit it to explain your requirement better? We may be able to help you figure out a better table structure than what you've proposed.

Comment: @RyanK . .  I get the output you want, but have no idea what the tables in your database look like.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited data you have provided, you could update that table using a `left join` to itself, checking whether `event` is not null for some earlier date e.g.

```
update events e1
left join events e2 on e2.date <= e1.date and e2.event is not null
set e1.occurred = case when e2.date is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end
```

The result of this update would be:

```
date        event       occurred
2020-02-08              No
2020-02-09              No
2020-02-10  pages.name  Yes
2020-02-11              Yes
2020-02-12              Yes
2020-02-13              Yes
2020-02-14              Yes
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a1562a7f767d0e15a936946b85622c2f)

For what you describe in your question you would need to expand this based on user ids and account numbers, but without more table structure information it's only possible to guess at a solution.